# Pass params with a promise

Tags: jquery

I loop through files dragged in to the window:

```
$.each(files, function(index, file){

    p.readFile(file).done(p.showFile);
});
```

They are read via this method:

```
p.readFile = function(file) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    fileReader.onload = function(event) {

        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };

    fileReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Once read files are passed to this method:

```
p.showFile = function(file, index) {

};
```

My question concerns the first loop:

```
$.each(files, function(index, file){

    p.readFile(file).done(p.showFile);
});
```

I need to pass the index of the loop and the returned file from the promise to the p.showFile method, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an anonymous function

```
$.each(files, function(index, file){

    p.readFile(file).done(function(data) {
        p.showFile(data, index);
    });

});
```

`$.each` creates it's own scope for each iteration, so another closure shouldn't be neccessary I think